# How can I navigate through this JSON response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am a new to JSON and facing problems accessing the following JSON returned by a REST Controller in AngularJS controller as below:

```
$scope.fetchFormData = function (empId) {
            CommonService.fetchform(empId).
                then(function(data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.employee));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.employee['fname']));
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.employee['lname']));
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.employee['location']));

                });

        }
```

Service:

```
fetchform : function(empId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            return $http.get(applink+'/fetchEmployee/'+empId)
            .success(function (data) {})
            .then(function(response) {
                if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                    console.log('fetchEmployee -> Data recieved :'+JSON.stringify(response.data));
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
                else {
                    // invalid response
                    console.log('fetchEmployee -> Invalid Data recieved');
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                }
            },function(response) {
                // something went wrong
                console.log('fetchEmployee -> Something went wrong');
                return $q.reject(response.data);
            });
        }
```

JSON:

```
{
  "employee": [{
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "location": "CA"
  }, {
    "fname": "Jenny",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "location": "CA"
  }]
}
```

I want to access the values of `fname`, `lname`, and `location` from the above response.

Comment: Access how?  In HTML?  JavaScript?  You need to show us your code for context

Comment: Where are you trying to access it? in angular controller?

Comment: you could check if you get a string or an object with `typeof variable`

Comment: yes in angular controller to be specific.

Comment: I guess what you want to do is just make the `.get()` call in the `fetchform` method and return that entire promise. Then when you do `CommonService.fetchform(empId)`, use the `then()` method, like you have already, to extract data from the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked using the following:

```
var values = data;
                var i=0;
                 angular.forEach(values,function(value,index){
                        console.log(' Value 723  '+value);
                        console.log(' Index 724  '+index);
                        i++;
                      angular.forEach(value,function(internalValue,key){

                            console.log('  InternalValue 725  '+JSON.stringify(internalValue));
                        console.log('  Internal Key 726  '+key2);

                      });


                 });
                 console.log(' Ctrl Counter 729  '+i);
```

Thanks for the suggestions guys. :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your controller if you have the JSON inside the variable 'data' then if you want to access the array you have to do:

```
data.employee --> [{John object}, {Jenny Object}]
```

So if you want to access the first employee you have to write:

```
data.employee[0]
```

And if you want to access the different values then:

```
data.employee[0].fname

data.employee[0].lname

data.employee[0].location
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a JSON object containing an array.

You can loop through this array as you would any array with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach) or a simple for loop in your controller.

In the HTML [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) will simulate a for loop and display 1 element for every item in the array.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.data = {
    "employee": [
      { "fname": "John",  "lname": "Doe", "location": "CA" },
      { "fname": "Jenny", "lname": "Doe", "location": "CA" }
    ]};
    $scope.data.employee.forEach(function(employee) {
        console.log(employee.fname);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.employee">{{item.fname}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a description of what you did, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an JS Object? People don't seem to realize that JSON really is a string.

check the type of the "JSON". If it's a string you need to parse it.

```
let str = '{"employee":[ {"fname":"John","lname":"Doe","location":"CA", {"fname":"Jenny","lname":"Doe","location":"CA"}]}';

let jsonObject = JSON.parse(str);
let name = jsonObject.employee[0].fname
```